# function to execute whenever cllocationmanager updates location

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I have a function in my `CllocationManagerDelegate` which I need to execute after my `CllocationManager` updates the location as soon as possible, but definitely not before. Is there any way to have a block of code execute as soon as the `CllocationManager` updates the location?

Comment: Have you tried calling function in `locationManager:didUpdateWithLocations:`?

Answer (score 1):

I would call your method, in the protocol method didUpdateLocations.

Like this:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

   // update any CLLocation values
   // And then call the method with the code that you need to execute ASAP
   self.yourMethod()
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks like the correct solution to the OP's problem. (voted)